# Rails "Show" routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble creating routes for my Rails app and google is returning mostly results for rails 2-3 from 5 or more years ago.

I'm trying to create a "show" route without using resources, as I need multiple show views.

If I do the following :

```
get "/parameters/:id" => "parameters#show"
```

Then if I directly type in the path, like "parameters/12" it will work, but when I run rake routes it doesn't show a path next to the route. And I can't seem to get a path to work for it.

I'm sure I'm forgetting something really obvious here, but I've been at this problem for a few hours and haven't found a solution so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are defining a custom route, Rails doesn't know how to generate the `_url` and `_path` named routes for you automatically.

In order to get the named routes generated, you need to help Rails by specifying the `as` argument

```
get '/parameters/:id', to: 'parameters#show', as: 'parameters_show'
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, fixed my problem!